# Is there a software that let multiple Android devices create a video wall?

Tags: multi-monitor, screen-sharing

Is there a software that allows multiple android devices to act like a single monitor for an application?

For example, if I put 4 android phones next to each other, could I see an RDP/VNC image/stream across all 4 of them?  Kind of like how some TVs or monitors need 4x HDMI cables to get to 4k, and the monitor shows each input in a quadrant.  Except in this case, it's 4 android phones acting as a single display.